# What's the difference between count(), size(), unique() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

After we groupby a DataFrame() in pandas, we can call the three methods. What's the difference between them?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({
    'key1':['a','a','b','b','a'],
    'key2':['one','two','one','two','one'],
    'data1':np.random.randn(5),
    'data2':np.random.randn(5)
})
grouped=df['data1'].groupby(df['key1'])
print(grouped.size(),grouped.nunique(),grouped.count())
```

The answer is the same.

Comment: count and size will return the the length of that df and nunique will return the unique value size

Comment: Count and size also differ in that count ignores NaN values, where as  size gets he size of the data including NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you have df like below

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'key1':['a','a','b','b','a'],
    'data1':[1,1,np.nan,1,2]
})
grouped=df['data1'].groupby(df['key1'])


grouped.size()# return length of value included the  NaN value

Out[413]:
key1
a    3
b    2
Name: data1, dtype: int64



grouped.count()# not include the NaN , it will ignore np.nan in b
Out[414]:
key1
a    3
b    1
Name: data1, dtype: int64

grouped.nunique() # only return the real unique value(exclude NaN) , in a it will be 1 , 2 so return 2 , at b it will be NaN and 1 so return 1
Out[415]: 
key1
a    2
b    1
Name: data1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Perfect examples. Thank you!